# How do I investigate input-to-state stability for $\dot{x}=-(1+u)x^3$

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory

I am wondering how to solve this problem. I am supposed to investigate the ISS stability. But I am having trouble seeing where to start.

How do I investigate input-to-state stability for $\dot{x}=-(1+u)x^3$

I have that:

for when $u(t)$ is identical to 0, the origin is asympotically stable
and that for a bounded input $u(t)$, every solution $x(t)$ is bounded.

Can anyone give me a hint or clue on where to start?

Comment: Do you mean $\dot{x} = -(1 + u)x$? If not how are $x$ and $x_3$ related?

Comment: I am sorry, there was a typo. I've edited it now.

Comment: What about the title

Comment: edited that now as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system is not input to state stable. Take the constant input $u = -2$:

$$
\dot{x} = -(1 + u) x^3 = -x^3 + 2 x^3 = x^3
$$

So although the input is bounded for all time the state can grow unbounded.

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: can I choose $u=0$? if not, why not?

Comment: @magn_hild That depends on what you are trying to achieve and what constraints you have on your input. If your goal is just to (mathematically) stabilize the system you can take $u = 0$ because this makes the system globally asymptotically stable (as you already wrote in your question).